# $n$-tuples of points of $\mathbb{C}$, identification.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Forgive me if this is a very silly question, but how can I see that the set of unordered $n$-tuples of points of $\mathbb{C}$ can be naturally identified with $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: Do you really mean unordered $n$-tuples, i.e., finite sets with $n$ elements? If so, then I don't think you are going to find any nice identification.

Comment: You could divide $\Bbb C^n$ into equivalence classes, where two $n$-tuples are equivalent if the sets of the coordinates are equal. Each tuple in $\Bbb C^n$ is then equivalent to at most $n!-1$ other tuples. Is this close enough?

Answer (score 1):

As Rob Arthan mentioned in the comments, there is no real standard identification of 'unordered tuples', which I am interpreting as [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), which is an identification (that is, a one-to-one correspondence.)

Rory Daulton's successive idea about using equivalence classes is a nice alternative that could be implemented in a couple of ways.

- You could identify two tuples of $\Bbb C^n$ *as multisets* (that is, two tuples having the same elements with the same multiplicities are equivalent.)
- A coarser partition would be obtained if you required two tuples to be equal *as sets*.

The first option seems to be the best fit for the original question, but the second one seems worthy of mention.