# Set of unordered $n$-tuples of points of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ can be identified with $\mathbb{CP}^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

This is a followup question to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414809/n-tuples-of-points-of-mathbbc-identification).

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$. What is the easiest way to see that the set of unordered $n$-tuples of points of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ can be identified with $\mathbb{CP}^n$?